# Generating rooms with Forge lib in Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a few questions:

1. Does `Data visualization API` work if i use room extract from naviswork?
2. I cant generating rooms from revit, what im doing wrong? my `Derivative` code below:

```
            List<JobPayloadItem> outputs = new List<JobPayloadItem>();
            JobPayloadItem jpli = new JobPayloadItem(JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Svf2,new List<JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum>(){JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._2d,JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3d});
            advanced advancedsetting = new advanced();
            jpli.Advanced = advancedsetting;
            outputs.Add(jpli);
```

with class advanced:

```
        public class advanced: IJobPayloadItemAdvanced
        {
            public bool generateMasterViews { get; set; } = true;

            public string ToJson()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, both AecModelData and Master view are Revit-only features on Model Derivative API, so the DataViz extension cannot get room data from the Navisworks models by the current design.

Here is a working code snippet for submitting the master view translation request with Forge .net SDK

```cs
var advOutputPayload = new JobSvf2OutputPayloadAdvanced();
advOutputPayload.GenerateMasterViews = true;

// prepare the payload
List<JobPayloadItem> outputs = new List<JobPayloadItem>()
{
    new JobPayloadItem(
        JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Svf2,
        new List<JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum>()
        {
            JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._2d,
            JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3d
        },
        advOutputPayload
    )
};

JobPayload job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(objModel.objectName), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs));
```